# Crafting items - magic possible?

Tags: neverwinter-nights-2, neverwinter-nights

Sometimes I still play first series, however I never put any skill points into armor crafting or weapon crafting especially when there are so many powerful items in Underdark campaign I wonder if it really worth doing these items? Can you make fast gold out of it , can you make magical armor or weapon?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can make magical stuff. Whether it's useful will depend on your character, though somebody in your party will probably benefit tremendously from custom weapons. I found Keen to be a particularly valuable attribute, since most of my builds relied on crits (My dual-wielding kukri weapon master/thief dealt critical hits 55% of the time, gibbing most enemies on the first sneak attack).

In later NWN2 expansions you can craft some especially potent items, especially from unique materials (Belt of +8 strength, for example). You could do some pretty crazy stuff in the original NWN2 campaigns too, like the mithril full plate wearable by a bard (with the skill that lets bards wear medium armor, of course).